# How to configure a General Working Set in Eclipse?

Tags: eclipse

Use case:

- I need to search strings (variable, methods...) in some specific project folders.
- Usually for this I'm creating a working set for that project.
- If I'm importing another project in the workspace I need to manually redefine a working set for that project.
- In my specific case, every imported project has the same folder structure so that it's anoying to define a working set each time I
  import another project. I need to add a general working set to the
  selected resource so that the result will be: search for a string in
  the selected resource using the general defined folder structure in
  the working set.
- I've searched on the internet and I couldn't find a way to avoid creating a working set for every new imported project.

Question: Is this posibility available in Eclipse?

Comment: Can you give me a reference please ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you said that all your project have the same structure(hope the same nature to) you can use this plugin for eclipse and select

- **Nature Working Set**: Projects are automatically added to/removed from
  the working set based on their natures

https://code.google.com/p/javadude/wiki/DynamicWorkingSets

Answer (score 0):

Yes is posible: first import all projects in workspace then when you create the working space at the menu where you write the name of working set, you also have to define the working set content, check all projects that you want to be part of that working set. See tutorial here:

http://eclipse.dzone.com/articles/eclipse-working-sets-explained

[image]

Comment: I'm not able to import all projects since I don't need them all at first (I don't know them all), so the idea is to apply the working set configuration also for the new imported project without editing an existing working set

Comment: you can also take a look here: http://www.eclipsezone.com/articles/filters-workingsets/